# SWC debug or release version

Tags: flash, swc

Are there debug and release versions of swc's, I only noticed the option of creating a swc, If there are debug or release versions how can we create the debug version in flash professional.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there are, but I'm not sure what your options are in Flash CS. I would imagine that the default is the debug version - because the final compilation will remove debug info from the SWC, if you are making a release build.

Comment: Under SWF option (not for SWC) there's a check box for "Permit Debugging", I believe this setting applies to swc also by default.